# Code won't run and the debugger isn't giving any output

Tags: java, debugging

I'm doing a debugging exercise for my java class. I need to fix a code that is meant to determine how much money you'd have each day if you doubled it everyday after starting with a penny. It is then supposed to stop after 30 days.

This is the code I have that currently only outputs 'After day 1 you have .02":

```
// Start with a penny
// double it every day
// how much do you have in a 30-day month?
public class DebugSix1
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      final int DAYS = 30;
      double money = 0.01;
      int day = 1;
      while(day < DAYS);
      {
         money = 2 * money;
         ++day;
         System.out.println("After day " + day +
            " you have " + money);
      }
   }
}
```

This is the code it gave me to start

```
// Start with a penny
// double it every day
// how much do you have in a 30-day month?
public class DebugSix1
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      final int DAYS = 30;
      double money = 0.01;
      int day = 1;
      while(day > DAYS);
      {
         money = 2 * money;
         ++days;
         System.out.println("After day " + day +
            " you have " + moneyAmt);
      }
   }
}
```

I am completely out of ideas and it seems everything I try only makes it worse.

Comment: while(day < DAYS); extra ; .

Comment: "isn't working" what is the expected output and actual output.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam Oops. my apologies. I'm very tired at the moment and realize that wasn't very specific. The expected out put is supposed to be "After day (day) you have (money). It is then supposed to repeat that output for a total of 30 days. I can screenshot the expected output if my explanation isn't making sense.

Comment: @arundeepchohan I have been racking my brain for the last two hours, rewriting and rewriting this program over and over again, and not once did I realize there was a semicolon ending the while loop. Thank you sir, you are a godsend

Comment: semicolons are one of the most troublesome things to look out for. np.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had a ; after the while(day < DAYS).

```
public class DebugSix1
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      final int DAYS = 30;
      double money = 0.01;
      int day = 1;
      while(day < DAYS)
      {
         money = 2 * money;
         ++day;
         System.out.println("After day " + day +
            " you have " + money);
      }
   }
}
```